# NEHotspotConfigurationManager not creating/joining hotspot

Tags: ios, swift3, ios11, nehotspothelper

I am trying to create/add a Hotspot configuration in iOS 11 installed device.

My code is as follows

```
let hotspotConfig = NEHotspotConfiguration(ssid: "testNetwork")
hotspotConfig.joinOnce = true
NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply(hotspotConfig) { (configurationError) in
    if configurationError != nil {
      print("error")
      print(configurationError!.localizedDescription)
    } else {
      print("success")
    }        
}
```

When i try to run the code. Device prompts for permissions as the following:-

```
"AppName" wants to join Wi-Fi Network "testNetwork"
```

But on tapping "Join", I am getting the following response

```
Unable to join the network "testNetwork"
```

However, on debug console "success" is getting printed.

Please tell me what am i doing wrong.

Comment: You're probably seeing success because the configuration was successfully added.  That is, it's added like any other "saved" WiFi you may have set up in the past (e.g., your home network, the office wifi).  At that point, I can only guess why it failed.  My short list would be WiFi signal strength or that the configuration you successful saved had a typo or something invalid.

Comment: @Rob : Well.. i think i won't be able to create a hotspot from code(which i was hoping i could, hence the attempt). i can only join one.  However i am not quite sure.  Can i create a hotspot from code, or can only join one ?

Comment: You're right. No, you can't _create_ a new hotspot from code on iOS. NEHotspotConfiguration simply makes it a little easier to connect to a pre-existing WiFi network/WiFi peripheral.

Comment: @PawanJoshi I have same issue. How can you resolved?

Answer (score 1):

The network is being added to the device's known network list, making it available to be auto joined.  Unless you have a nearby network named "testNetwork" it will always fail to join.

Answer (score 1):

**If you enter the ssid with spaces then it will not work.**

In my case my ssid contained spaces & i got the success in console but with error alert. After removing the spaces it's working fine.

Answer (score -1):

**Enable Hotspot on App Id configure services**

[image: Enable Hotspot on App Id configure services]

**After Enable Hotspot Configuration**

[image: After Enable Hotspot Configuration]

Comment: Hello, for some reason I cant get hotspot as one of the options in capabilities. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani it is because you need a developer account for this to capabilities to work

Comment: Thanks!! I found this out since when I removed my account from xCode, it was available. ticking it it showed I need a paid developer account.

Comment: Where do we get to this screen in order to configure it?